# angular dropdown not working (mdbootstrap)

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I added mdbootstrap to the project using this tutorial :
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/installation/

My angular.json:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
          "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
          "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/mdb.scss",
          "node_modules/animate.css/animate.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
          "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
@NgModule({
imports: [
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
]
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul
    class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end"
    aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
  >
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My profile</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

how it looks in  docs
[image]

actual result
[image]

the main issue is that the dropdown not working when pressing on the user avatar

Comment: Do you see any error in console ?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I can see you selected **css** as the stylesheet for your angular project. MDBootstrap uses **scss** as the required stylesheet.

Please make sure you select **"scss"** stylesheet when creating the new Angular project.

Then use **ng add mdb-angular-ui-kit**

accept to install **BrowserAnimations** when asked